# Як українською перекласти "Само собой разумеется"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Невже "Само собою розуміється"?

Comment: Коли запитуєте значення терміну з іноземної мови, завжди вказуйте (1) приблизний переклад своїми словами: не всі з нас знають усі іноземні мови; (2) контекст, в якому термін має сі використовувати; (3) продемонструйте спробу знайти відповідь самостійно; (4) вкажіть, чим знайдені вами варіанти не підходять.

Answer (score 17):

«**Ясна́ річ**».

Наприклад:

> Ясна річ, він хоче застукати злодіїв на гарячому (Григорій Косинка, Новели, 1962, 185)

Answer (score 10):

**`ЯСНО ЯК БОЖИЙ ДЕНЬ`**, казали моя бабуся.

СУМ підтверджує:

[ЯСНО](http://sum.in.ua/s/jasno)

> 3. у знач. присудк. сл. **Те саме, що `зрозуміло`**
>
> ♦ **Ясно як [божий] день** див. `день`.

[ДЕНЬ, дня, чол.](http://sum.in.ua/s/denj)

> **Ясно як [божий] день** — ***зовсім ясно, очевидно***.
>
> — Що вдарити треба неодмінно першими — це Боженкові.. було ясно як
>   день, бо ж атакуючий завжди має перевагу (Юрій Смолич, Реве та
>   стогне.., 1960, 341)

Comment: Ще може бути *цілком ясно*, але думаю це більше діалектизм.

Answer (score 8):

Хоча це схоже на кальку з російської, але СУМ-11 наводить цей вираз у статті [розумітися](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozumitysja) і наводить навіть цитату з листа Лесі Українки:

> ♦ **Розуміється само собою** що — що-небудь не потребує доказів, є очевидним для всіх. *Коли я і в Одесу не поїду (се **само собою тепер розуміється**), і тебе на свята не діждусь, то буде кепський інтерес... (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 214).*

А ось і саме означення слова "розумітися" яке може вживатися як безособове дієслово:

> **2.** **також над чим, рідко за чим, *безос.*** Мислитися, сприйматися, матися на увазі. *Коли згадаємо, як тісно і самовільно **розумілося** те, що дозволено і недозволено в літературі, — тоді зрозуміємо ту бурю гніву, яку викликав Франко серед галицьких читачів своїм новаторством* (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 32); *— А Шовкун тут уже очі видивився виглядаючи, — казав Черниш.. «Але я виглядав тебе далеко більше за Шовкуна, — **розумілося** за цими словами..»* (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 396).

У корпусах також є декілька прикладів (проте, не багато) використання цього виразу.

Паралельний російсько-український корпус - ["Пан Халявський"](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=%28lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22%29&mysent=&mysize=9383924&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&req=%F1%EE%E1%EE%FE%20%F0%EE%E7%F3%EC%B3%BA%F2%FC%F1%FF) Квітки-Основ'яненка у перекладі Б. Д. Антоненка Давидовича:

> - Само собою розуміється, що я, як об'явлений пестунчик їхній, мав найбільше пестощів, ніж старші брати мої.
> - Само собою розуміється, що я не казав таких слів, бо не знав про існування і значення їх,..
> - Само собою розуміється, що наречена нічого не знає й не має права вибирати, а одержує і кохає того, кого їй дадуть.

Корпус [Mova.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) за пошуком словоформ "собою" + "розуміється" у художній прозі дає 10 результатів:

> - Само собою розуміється, що таке життя йому швидко збридло і що він ждав весни, як спасенія душі. (Іван Франко, Boa Constrictor)
> - Серпанок сам собою розуміється. (ЧЕРЕЗ КЛАДКУ ОЛЬГА КОБИЛЯНСЬКА, 1940)
> - Це саме собою розуміється, прошу пані, бо ж, ясна річ: душа, що визначається такими високими прикметами, мусить без сумніву жити в гарнім жіночім тілі … (ОСИП ТУРЯНСЬКИЙ, "Син землі", 1933)
> - А само собою розуміється, що без танка та без бомби на сто двадцять п'ять пудів народного господарства не відновиш. (Остап Вишня, Зібрання творів у 4 томах)
> - На селі, само собою розуміється, не так, як у місті. (Остап Вишня)
> - Та само собою розуміється, що - школа, клуб, хатачитальня, фізкультура, сільськогосподарський гурток! (Остап Вишня, Зібрання творів у 4 томах)
> - Бо ж, само собою розуміється, працювати тепер для своєї власної держави не те, що колись працювати на хазяїна … (Остап Вишня, Зібрання творів у 4 томах)
> - Ми, само собою розуміється, не від того, щоб побувати на Місяці, чи на Марсі, чи навіть на Сатурні й на Нептуні … (Остап Вишня, Зібрання творів у 4 томах)
> - Будинок для клубу й було збудовано, але за Врангеля тут, само собою розуміється, була церква. (Остап Вишня, Зібрання творів у 4 томах)
> - І, само собою розуміється, « найкраще од усіх » … (Остап Вишня, Зібрання творів у 4 томах)

У підкорпусі публіцистичних текстів аж одна цитата:

> Сталін говорив, що « само собою розуміється, нація, як всяке історичне явище, має свою історію: початок і кінець ». (Микола Хвильовий, 1928)

Answer (score 4):

[Зі словника Виргана, Пилинської](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> само собою зрозуміло; звичайна (певна) річ; (*іноді*) самозрозуміла річ.

Answer (score 3):

[Само собою [зрозуміло]](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%22)<sup>[[1]](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/7/53409/101221.html)[[2]](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)[[3]](http://www.lecture.in.ua/praktichnij-rosijseko-ukrayinsekij-slovnik.html?page=12)</sup>

---

<sup>1. Українсько-російский і російсько-український фразеологичний словник (Олейник І. С., Сидоренко М. М.)

2. Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)

3. Практичний російсько-український словник: Найуживаніші слова і вислови. — 2000. (Непийвода Н. Ф.)</sup>

Comment: По-моєму, у Вас все правильно. То модератор перестарався.

Comment: @Follower, Re: «Яке питання — така відподвідь» — не згоден; неякісне запитання [не є підставою](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/192/) для неякісних відповідей. Тим більше, що «після зауваження модератора, автор не вніс ясності». Це може бути підставою для close-vote. Я, насправді, сидів і чекав, коли з'являться голоси за закриття запитання. Натомість, я бачу +8 голосів — НМД. не заслугованих.

Comment: Як на мене, абсолютно нормальна відповідь: (1) за темою; (2) чітко; (3) з джерелами.

Answer (score 2):

"Це певна річ", "це є зрозуміло".

Джерело: [С. І. Головащук «Російсько-український словник сталих словосполучень» (2001, Київ, «Наукова думка», 640 сторінок)](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/s).

Comment: Тому, хто поставив «-1»: взагалі вважається хорошим стилем — пояснювати, через що знижено оцінку.

Comment: @Sasha, -1 поставив я. Пояснення — [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57733/discussion-between-bytebuster-and-sasha).